# Material UI multiple dropdown menus in navbar

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I am trying to create a navbar with a series of material ui dropdown menus, but I am running into an issue that I can't seem to solve. When I click a navbar item all of the dropdowns open on top of each other under the menu item I clicked. Below is the code:

```
import styles from "./AppNav.module.css";
import { navData } from "./navData.js";
import Link from "next/link";
import {Button, Menu, MenuItem } from '@mui/material';
import { style } from "@mui/system";
import { useState } from "react";

export default function AppNav(props:any){
    const [anchorEl, setAnchorEl] = useState<null | HTMLElement>(null);
    const open = Boolean(anchorEl);
    const handleClick = (event: React.MouseEvent<HTMLButtonElement>) => {
      setAnchorEl(event.currentTarget);
    };
    const handleClose = () => {
      setAnchorEl(null);
    };
    return(
        <>
         <ul id="menu-topLvl" className={styles.Menu}>
            <li><Button><Link className={styles.homeLink} href="/">Home</Link></Button></li>
            {navData.map((navItem, index) => {
                return <li key={index}>
                    <Button
                        id={navItem.navHeading}
                        key={navItem.id}
                        aria-controls={open ? navItem.navHeading : undefined}
                        aria-haspopup="true"
                        aria-expanded={open ? 'true' : undefined}
                        onClick={handleClick}
                    >
                        {navItem.navHeading}
                    </Button>
                    <Menu
                        id={navItem.navHeading}
                        anchorEl={anchorEl}
                        open={open}
                        onClose={handleClose}
                        MenuListProps={{
                            'aria-labelledby': navItem.navHeading,
                        }}
                    >
                        {navItem.lvlTwo.map((subNav, index) =>
                            <MenuItem
                                key={index}
                                onClick={handleClose}
                            >
                                <Link href={subNav.link}>
                                    {subNav.subNavHeading}
                                </Link>
                            </MenuItem>
                        )}
                    </Menu>
                </li>
            })}
        </ul> 
        </>
    )
}
```

and the data:

```
   {
        id: 2,
        navHeading: 'Merchant',
        link: '',
        hasSubs:true,
        lvlTwo:[
            {
                subNavHeading: 'Statement',
                link:"Merchant/Statement.tsx",
            },
            {
                subNavHeading: 'Invoice',
                link:"",
            },
            {
                subNavHeading: 'Transaction Lookup',
                link:"",
            },{
                subNavHeading: 'Batch Lookup',
                link:"",
            },{
                subNavHeading: 'Funding Lookup',
                link:"",
            },{
                subNavHeading: 'Funded Transaction',
                link:"",
            },{
                subNavHeading: 'Statement',
                link:"",
            },{
                subNavHeading: 'Submitted Transaction',
                link:"",
            },{
                subNavHeading: 'Returns',
                link:"",
            }
        ]
    },{
        id: 3,
        navHeading: 'Partner',
        link: '',
        hasSubs:true,
        lvlTwo:[
            {
                subNavHeading: 'Statement',
                link:"",
            },{
                subNavHeading: 'Invoice',
                link:"",
            },{
                subNavHeading: 'Funded Transaction',
                link:"",
            },{
                subNavHeading: 'Submitted Transaction',
                link:"",
            },
        ]
    },{
        id: 4,
        navHeading: 'Processing',
        link: '',
        hasSubs:true,
        lvlTwo:[
            {
                subNavHeading: 'Transaction Detail',
                link:"",
            },{
                subNavHeading: 'Transaction Summary',
                link:"",
            },{
                subNavHeading: 'Transactions By Merchant',
                link:"",
            },{
                subNavHeading: 'Transactions By Batch',
                link:"",
            },{
                subNavHeading: 'Return Summary',
                link:"",
            },{
                subNavHeading: 'Boarding Stats',
                link:"",
            },{
                subNavHeading: 'Risk Summary',
                link:"",
            },{
                subNavHeading: 'Uncollected Invoices/ACH Exceptions',
                link:"",
            },{
                subNavHeading: 'ACH Exceptions',
                link:"",
            },{
                subNavHeading: 'Unsettled Transation Voids',
                link:"",
            },{
                subNavHeading: 'Bank account Update Logs',
                link:"",
            },
        ]
    },{
        id: 5,
        navHeading: 'Accounting',
        link: '',
        hasSubs:true,
        lvlTwo:[
            {
                subNavHeading: 'Returns',
                link:"",
            },{
                subNavHeading: 'Compensation',
                link:"",
            },{
                subNavHeading: 'Income Statement',
                link:"",
            },{
                subNavHeading: 'Income/Charges',
                link:"",
            },{
                subNavHeading: 'Processing Balances',
                link:"",
            },{
                subNavHeading: 'Return Balances',
                link:"",
            },{
                subNavHeading: 'Colonnade 1099k',
                link:"",
            },{
                subNavHeading: 'Colonnade 1099k Summary',
                link:"",
            },{
                subNavHeading: 'ODFI Exposure',
                link:"",
            },{
                subNavHeading: 'File Entries',
                link:"",
            },{
                subNavHeading: 'Activated Merchant',
                link:"",
            },{
                subNavHeading: 'Aging Deposits',
                link:"",
            },
        ]
    },
]
```

I don't understand how to make only the one menu item open at a time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have one `open` prop for all of the menus.
Try to store opened menu name or id and then in menu check if current menu name\id is equal to one that you store in state.

**UPDATE**

I'll add here a basic explanation, this wouldn't be with your actual code, just a minimal example to get you some better understanding

```
const menus = ["profile", "items", "cart"];

const Menu = () => {
  const [openedItem, setOpenedItem] = useState("") // here you can set some menu item so it can be opened by default

  const handleMenuItemOpen = (itemId) => {
    setOpenedItem(itemId)
  }

  return (
    <Menu>
       {menus.map(menuItem => (
          <MenuItemComponent
             isOpened={openedItem === menuItem}
             handleOpen={() => setOpenedItem(menuItem)}
          >
            {menuItem}
          </MenuItemComponent>
       ))}
    </Menu>
  )
}
```

(Menu and MenuItemComponent are just some abstract components, in your case you should use what you are currently use, I used them just to get rid of a lot of code and make more focus on main part)

This is just a basic example. Here is what happened here, when you click on some item, you set its id (any unique property that you have, in case of predefined static list of menus you can use even index of menu item, it will not affect your app behavior, but I do not recommend using indexes just because you can develop a bad habit), and when you render your menu items components, it will check for each component is it's id equal to id that is currently set as opened. So only one component will have an isOpened={true} in case if you have unique menu items list.

In your case, you have one boolean prop "open" that you use for all of your menu items, so when it became true, each of your menu items became opened.

Hope it helped!

Comment: could you give me an example? I'm pretty new to react and I'm having trouble figuring out where to do the actual check

Comment: I updated my answer with some basic example and explanation to it

Comment: Thank you! After your update I was able to make it work. I do have a new issue now with the close functionality but I think that is suited for a different post.